# Can someone help me with structs in C?

Tags: c, input, struct

Why does this only print not found. The idea of course is that the user types a name and it prints their name and number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* number;
}
person;

int main(void)
{
    person people[3];
    
    people[0].name = "sam";
    people[0].number = "99912222";
    
    people[1].name = "tom";
    people[1].number = "11122222";

    people[2].name = "harry";
    people[2].number = "12299933";
    
    
    char boot;
    printf("Enter: ");
    scanf("%c", &boot);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(people[i].name, &boot) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s=%s\n",people[i].name, people[i].number);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Not Found\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The arguments to `strcmp()` must be strings. `&boot` is not a string.

Comment: You're reading a single character into `boot`.  You then attempt to treat it as a null-terminated string.  What makes you think that the byte following `boot` contains a `\0` value?  And why do you only want to input a single character?  Since none of your names are one character long, the comparison will fail unless you get very unlucky with the garbage values that follow `boot`.

Comment: I thought that was the issue, I'm not sure how to make &boot a string so I can pass it to strcomp.

Comment: If you want to read a single word from the user, you should use the `%s` `scanf` conversion format specifier instead of `%c`. If you want to read an entire line from the user (i.e. possibly several words), then you should use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`. In any case, `boot` is only able to store a single character, so you should change it to an array, for example like this: `char boot[100]`. That way, it can store 99 characters in addition to the terminating null character.

Comment: Using pointers to string literals like in `people[0].name = "sam";` is calling for trouble sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` means get a single character from input. Therefore, if you enter 'abc', all you will get is 'a'.

Another extremely important thing is that, `boot` is declared as a single char, i.e. `char boot;`.

A `char` occupies 1 byte in memory. So, when you pass `&boot`(pointer to the address of `boot`) to `strcmp()`, it will first check the length of the arguments. How will it find its length? Simple, by looking upto the '\0' character in memory. Since you have declared `boot` as a single char, it only contains the first character of the input. Hence, `strcmp()` will potentially access memory that probably shouldn't be accessed. This results in Undefined Behaviour. To avoid it, you will need to keep `boot` **atleast n bytes where n > 1 and the n'th byte must be a null byte if there are no other null bytes present in between the 1st and the n'th byte.**

Short note: **As far as I know**, Pointers point to the address of the first byte of what you assign it to.
So,

```
...
// imagine buf[0] is 0x121 and buf[1] is 0x122
char buf[2];
char *ptr = buf;
// ptr will point to 0x121
...
```

Try:

```
...
    int nbytes_to_accept = 128;
    char boot[nbytes_to_accept + 2];
    /* name (nbytes_to_accept) +
     * [Extra character to check if name is higher than the max] +
     * LF/NULL
     * = nbytes_to_accept + 2
     */
    printf("Enter: ");
    fgets(boot, sizeof boot, stdin);
    boot[strcspn(boot, "\n")] = '\0'; // remove LF, as we don't need it
    if (strlen(boot) > nbytes_to_accept) {
        printf("ERROR: Name cannot be larger than %d characters.\n", nbytes_to_accept);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Make sure to properly get the size of
     * the elements of the list, without
     * doing a sizeof on a pointer, if this
     * list becomes extendable and stuff.
     * One way would be to store the size somewhere
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(people[i].name, boot) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s=%s\n",people[i].name, people[i].number);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Not Found\n");
    return 1;
}
```